# Horizontal slide list jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, sliding

I have the following HTML markup

```
<ul class="banner"> 
    <li class="current" id="0"><img src="images/first.png"/></li>
    <li id="1"><img src="images/second.png" /></li>
    <li id="2"><img src="images/third.png" /></li>
</ul>
```

I want the first item to slide out & be replaced by the second item & so on. The end item will 'loop back round' to the first item. The math logic for this is simple.

The first item successfully slides out but the list then 'collapses' to a 0 height and the second `<li>` does not replace it.

Here's what I have in jQuery:

```
// GLOBALS
$currentBannerImage;
// Before page is created
$(document).delegate("#indexpage", "pagebeforecreate", function()
{
// Get non current banner images
$nonCurrentBannerListItems = $("ul.banner li").not(".current");
// Hide them
    if ($nonCurrentBannerListItems.size() > 0)
    {
        $nonCurrentBannerListItems.each(function()
        {
            $(this).hide();
        }
       $currentBannerImage = 0;
    }
});
});
// When page has successfully loaded & been inserted into DOM
$(document).delegate("#indexpage", "pagebeforecreate", function()
{
// Prevent default image dragging behavior on desktops
$("img").on("dragstart",function(dragEvent)
{
    dragEvent.preventDefault();
});

$("ul.banner li").swipeleft(function()
{
    // Get Swiped element id
    // Get Current Element
    $currentElementID = $currentBannerImage;

    $newElementID = $currentElementID+1;

    // Slide the touched element left
    $('#'+currentElementID).hide("slide", {direction: "left"},1000);
    $('#'+$newElementID).show("slide",{direction: "right"},1000);
});
});
```

Comment: where is the problem ?

Comment: Hi Paul, for questions like this, it really helps to create a JSFiddle.net demo. There are people who want to help but only have time to help with the problem, not setting up the environment for testing, particularly since that can involve some assumptions that might break/fix the problem without knowing it.

Comment: Also, I noticed your `id` attributes are using invalid names.  [Regard the W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name).  ID names must start with a letter to be valid HTML.  They can't start with a number (although I believe JavaScript will still usually work).